# Type hinting a decorator that injects function parameters / changes the function signature

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, functools

I'm trying to write a decorator that can be used to suppress exceptions raised in a decorated function and return a default value instead.

I have struggled with getting the type hints correct, but all I'm left with now is an `error: Unexpected keyword argument "default"`.

Is there any way I can add the injected default (keyword) argument to the signature of the decorated method so that it is not unexpected anymore?

The decorator is implemented as follows:

```py
import functools
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec, Callable

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


def suppress(
    default: object = None,
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, R]], Callable[P, R | object]]:

    def decorator_suppress(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R | object]:
        functools.wraps(
            func,
        )

        def wrapper_suppress(
            *args: P.args,
            default: object = default,
            **kwargs: P.kwargs,
        ) -> R | object:

            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                return default

        return wrapper_suppress

    return decorator_suppress
```

The decorator should work in such a way that the default value can either be set as a parameter on the decorator itself, but also as a keyword argument on the function it decorates (to make for easier unit-testing)

```py
@suppress(default="foo!")
def foo(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


a = foo(1, 1)
b = foo(1, "2")
c = foo(1, "2", default="bar!")

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

results in:

```
2
foo!
bar!
```

The mypy error:

```
error: Unexpected keyword argument "default" for "foo"  [call-arg]
```

is (obviously) raised from:

```py
c = foo(1, "2", default="bar!")
```

Comment: `ParamSpec` does not support concatenating keyword arguments as of now. Only positional-only arguments can be added.